# How can I verify successful replication of two domain controllers

Tags: domain-controller, windows-server-2012-r2

I have in my environment two redundant Windows Server 2012R2 domain controller.

How can I verify successful replication of two domain controllers? On the domain controller are roles installed like AD DS, DNS and WINS For example, are there a list of command lines or something like this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a command prompt on each DC run "repadmin /showrepl". That will show you the status of replication from each DC's perspective.

Note that if your DNS zones are not AD integrated then they won't replicate with AD.

I've never heard of WINS being integrated with AD and as such it wouldn't replicate with AD either.

Answer (score 4):

Use `dcdiag /v` or some other option of the `dcdiag` command.

To make it easy to read I always do `dcdiag /v > dcdiag.txt`. Also check `repadmin /showrepl` to check replication between DCs

Answer (score 3):

The answer for AD has been given, so I will skip that.

For DNS you can look in the DNS Events section (in the DNS Manager tool) for Event 6522: "A more recent version, version 7667 of zone domain.local was found at the DNS server at 10.10.10.15. Zone transfer is in progress."  You will receive this message after adding a record on 1 DNS server and then checking the event log on the other server.  If you are looking to script this then you would do an nslookup against both servers for a specific (test) record existing in both locations.

nslookup (recordTOLookUP) (nameserver)

> nslookup record.domain.local server1.domain.local
>
> nslookup record.domain.local server2.domain.local

For WINS, no replication happens upon installing the WINS role to each server.  You must manually configure push/pull replication and then verify in the event logs or via the WINS database manually on both servers.  Once replication is established, the netsh commands for WINS (available on Win XP, but not on Windows 7) will allow you to script testing replication.

```
 check name NameList={Name1*03,Name1*00,Name1*20} ServerList={10.2.2.2,10.2.2.3}
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490946.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think that's what the Active Directory Replication Status Tool is for
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30005

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, thats one of the possibility. I edited my question, to be sure that I can explain my question clearly. This tool is only for the AD replication without DNS and WINS, is that right? If yes, I need also for DNS or WINS. It could be also a list of command lines.

Comment: Ah.  OK So it's possible if your DNS zone is active directory integrated that this might also cover it (I haven't tried this myself) but if it's not then I'm not entirely sure.  Some of these other guys might have better answers.