# Active Directory Mismatch

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Active Directory Mistmatch how do I fix this?

I have 2 x 2008 R2 Domain Controllers and a 2008 Domain Controller and I was trying to add a 2012 R2 Domain Controller.

The Schema Version of my domain is 69 on one of the 2008 R2 DCs and 47 on all my other DCs.

How do I fix this so I can add a new DC?

Comment: that doesn't sound right. There is only one AD Schema Version... Or are those different domains?

Comment: Same domain. I need to update the schema version for all domain controllers but I don't know how?

Comment: That's the point, you do not upgrade the schema on domain controllers, just on the whole domain. If a domain controller does not report the highest schema version, then you have an Active Directory replication problem, and I suggest you check the replication

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/581295/how-can-i-verify-successful-replication-of-two-domain-controllers

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2734946 is the error I am getting

Comment: Cool. Now you have a KB Article to work with, and you can hopefully resolve the issue

Answer (score -1):

No need to waste time for searching.

1. Demote
   Outdated domain server
2. Metadata cleanup
3. Promote it again

[remove broken domain controller](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555846)

Comment: A good answer need more explanation than that.

Comment: What part of my answer is not clear to You ?